# How to rotate 4 (or more) images, fading between each one?

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I have 4 images, which I want to fade between each other in a loop. I have something like the following:

```
<img src="/images/image-1.jpg" id="featureImg1" />
<img src="/images/image-2.jpg" id="featureImg2" style="display:none;" />
<img src="/images/image-3.jpg" id="featureImg3" style="display:none;" />
<img src="/images/image-4.jpg" id="featureImg4" style="display:none;" />
```

I am up for revisions to the HTML, although I cannot use absolute positioning in this case. I am using jQuery else where on the site, so it's available. I also need to deal with an image not being loaded right away as the images are larger.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd highly recommend the [jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin. It may do more than you're looking for in this case, but it's well structured and easy to setup. There's also a lightweight version called [jQuery Cycle Lite](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/) which just supports fade transitions.

Comment: Thxs...so glad to find that! Very small, especially just for fadding!

Comment: Ah so ~this~ is what all those adult website ads are using these days! .. cool

Comment: Scott, seems you visit a lot of adult websites!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `div` and an `img`, like so:

```
<div id="featureImgContainer">
    <img src="/images/image-1.jpg" id="featureImg" />
</div>
```

In your Javascript do something like this (pseudo-jQuery):

```
function rotateImage(newImage) {
    var oldImage = $("#featureImg").image();

    $("#featureImgContainer").css({backgroundImage: "url('" + oldImage + "')"}); // TODO Escape URL

    $("#featureImg").image(newImage).opacity(0).fadeIn();
}
```

Basically, we make the `div`'s background the "old" image, and the `img` the new one.  We set the `img` to 0 opacity, and fade it in, so it appears as if the old image is fading into the new one.  After the fade in, the `div` isn't shown any more.

Take care to set up the CSS appropriately to set the width/height of the `div` and the background position where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I have also found this extension to jQuery: http://www.linein.org/blog/2008/01/10/roate-image-using-jquery-with-plugin/

It seems to do it quite nicely, although a lot of code for not too much.

Edit: I also found the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) which I've used quite often and has been working quite well. It also has the ability to have "navigation" and prev/next buttons. Quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

you can stay with the core of jQuery and have a loop bring up the z-index..

it can be done in a very simple way...